# Retrieve index of JSON array from

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I have a standard JSON array returned to me which I have deserialized with JsonConvert, below being a simplified representative of my situation:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "21",
    },
  {
    "name": "Sally",
    "age": "18",
   },
 {
    "name": "Harry",
    "age": "25",
   }
]
```

...

```
Public Class myExample
  Public Property name as String
  Public Property age as Integer
End Class
```

...

```
Dim serverResponse as string = reader.ReadToEnd()
Dim jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of myExample))(serverResponse)
```

I can easily retrieve the values of name or age given the item index, e.g.,

```
Dim someValue = jsonResult.Item(1).name ' returns Sally
Dim someOther = jsonResult.Item(1).age  ' returns 18
```

Yet I wish to return the index (integer) of the array given the name: i.e., how might I search for Sally and retrieve the Item index integer (in this case 1), or in the case of John, return 0? I have not been able to achieve this with jsonResult.IndexOf(), or jsonResult.FindIndex() and searches have not been fruitful.

I have an extensive JSON and wish to loop through names on a dataGridViewer column, returning the ages of all names to another column.

Thanks for helping a novice out!

Comment: In that code, `jsonResult` is going to be a `List(of T)` naming it JSON confuses things because it isnt JSON any longer, but a common ordinary NET collection of objects.  You should be able to use the list as a datasource and see all your data there

Comment: Exactly.  `jsonResult.First(Function(x) x.name = "John")` will find the first match in the list, but that's just a standard LINQ search which has nothing to do with JSON.  If you need to find the item in the JSON string _before_ deserializing it, that's one thing, but once you've deserialized it, it's not JSON anymore, it's just a normal .NET list.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the pointers - my example is indeed poorly named since jsonResult is already deserialized.  In my example, I may have just found the solution through: jsonResult.FindIndex((Function(s) s.name.Equals(someNameToCheck))))

Comment: Yup, that'll work too.  It's just a list, so any method for finding an item in a list will work.  There's many ways to skin a cat. :)

Comment: Now that you understand it, why don't you go ahead and add your own answer to your question.

Comment: Note that you do not have to loop thru it to show the data in 2 column in a DGV -  `myDGV,DataSource = jsonResult` will do it for you

Comment: Thanks all for your great input! Plutonix, I will take a look at your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since deserialization in this manner results in List(of T), the index to the above example can be found through, for example:

```
jsonResult.FindIndex((Function(s) s.name.Equals(someNameToCheck))))
```

or any other method of finding an item in a list.